# Forward sentence by comma by partial sentence in org

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Strike `M-e` in org which invokes `org-forward-sentence` and thus move point to end of the sentence.

I desire to move by comma. When refer to `org-forward-sentence`, notice the last two lines of

```
(let ((sentence-end (concat (sentence-end) "\\|^\\*+ .*$")))
        (call-interactively #'forward-sentence)))))))
```

From the completed definition.

```
(defun org-forward-sentence (&optional _arg)
  "Go to end of sentence, or end of table field.
This will call `forward-sentence' or `org-table-end-of-field',
depending on context."
  (interactive)
  (if (and (org-at-heading-p)
       (save-restriction (skip-chars-forward " \t") (not (eolp))))
      (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
    (call-interactively #'forward-sentence))
    (let* ((element (org-element-at-point))
       (contents-end (org-element-property :contents-end element))
       (table (org-element-lineage element '(table) t)))
      (if (and table
           (>= (point) (org-element-property :contents-begin table))
           (< (point) contents-end))
      (call-interactively #'org-table-end-of-field)
    (save-restriction
      (when (and contents-end
             (> (point-max) contents-end)
             ;; Skip blank lines between elements.
             (< (org-element-property :end element)
            (save-excursion (goto-char contents-end)
                    (skip-chars-forward " \r\t\n"))))
        (narrow-to-region (org-element-property :contents-begin element)
                  contents-end))
      ;; End of heading is considered as the end of a sentence.
      (let ((sentence-end (concat (sentence-end) "\\|^\\*+ .*$")))
        (call-interactively #'forward-sentence)))))))
```

Then changed `dot` to comma

```
(let ((sentence-end (concat (sentence-end) "\\|^\\*+ ,*$"))) ;;changee . to ,
        (call-interactively #'forward-sentence)))))))
```

However, it proved wrong.

Where should I change within the original function.

```
 Define it as 
       (def org-forward-partial-sentence (&optional arg) 
and (global-set-key "\C-m"
```

Comment: If you want to move *only* by comma (not also by normal sentence-end punctuation) then why not just use `C-s ,`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `.` has special meaning in a regex context, see [(emacs)Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) in the manual.

A very simplistic modification could be,

```
(concat (sentence-end) "\\|^\\*+ .*$\\|,")
```

to move to `,` as well.

Instead of changing the entire function, you could just let bind `sentence-end` around `org-forward-sentence`, eg.

```
(defun my-org-forward-sentence ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sentence-end (concat (sentence-end) "\\|,")))
    (call-interactively #'org-forward-sentence)))
```